# Test that user was logged in successfully

Tags: django

How can I test that a user is logged in after submitting the registration form?

I tried the following but it returns `True` even before I added the login logic to my registration view.

```
def test_that_user_gets_logged_in(self):
    response = self.client.post(reverse('auth-registration'), 
                                { 'username':'foo', 
                                  'password1':'bar', 
                                  'password2':'bar' } )

    user = User.objects.get(username='foo')
    assert user.is_authenticated()
```

The code that's being tested:

```
class RegistrationView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'auth/registration.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = '/'

    def auth_login(self, request, username, password):
        '''
        Authenticate always needs to be called before login because it
        adds which backend did the authentication which is required by login.
        '''

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        '''
        Overwrite form_valid to login.
        '''

        #save the user
        response = super(RegistrationView, self).form_valid(form)

        #Get the user creditials
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

        #authenticate and login
        self.auth_login(self.request, username, password)

        return response
```

Comment: Did you try `response.request.user.is_authenticated()`?

Comment: I did but the request object doesn't have a user object.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

> **This is not the best answer**. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871564/307511
>
> [Chronial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758345/chronial) has given
>   an excellent example on how to make this assertion below. His answer
>   better than mine for nowadays code.

---

The most straightforward method to test if a user is logged in is by testing the Client object:

```
self.assertIn('_auth_user_id', self.client.session)
```

You could also check if a specific user is logged in:

```
self.assertEqual(int(self.client.session['_auth_user_id']), user.pk)
```

As an additional info, the `response.request` object is not a `HttpRequest` object; instead, it's an ordinary dict with some info about the actual request, so it won't have the `user` attribute anyway.

Also, testing the `response.context` object is not safe because you don't aways have a context.

Comment: Just as an added assurance you can do the same test but using the value of the `SESSION_KEY` variable.  Like this:

`from django.contrib.auth import SESSION_KEY`
`self.assertTrue(SESSION_KEY in self.client.session)`

You can see this being used in the auth app in the Django framework: [github...test/views.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py#L51)  

They also have a convenience function for testing that a user has logged out: [github...test/views.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py#L429)

Comment: Thanks for complementing, I was not aware of that. :)

Comment: The first comment link is broken - this is where it is hosted now - https://github.com/django/django-old/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py

Comment: How do you crack the session open? The only thing `self.client.session` gives me is a `SessionStore` object.

Comment: @AdamStarrh A `SessionStore` object should be a dict-like object. Try to `dict()` it and see what you get.

Comment: This is not correct – it will not correctly validate the login in all contexts and should not be used. See my answer below for a more correct version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35871564/758345

Comment: @Chronial Interesting. Could you please give as an example one context in which this method would not work and yours would instead? I'm not arguing in favor of my version -- Actually I like yours --, I'm just curious. Also, consider that the Django version by the time of my answer is around 1.2~1.3.

Comment: The main difference is that `auth.get_user` will call `get_user()` on the appropriate backend and will also validate the session hash. This bid me because I didn't [update the session hash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.update_session_auth_hash) after a password change (which logs the user out), and our tests didn't catch it.

Comment: I was updating some old code and noticed that the `_auth_user_id` was an int in Django 1.7, but a string in Django 1.8.7. I see that the answer is already updated with `int()` to accommodate that, but just saying this for the record.

Comment: @S.Kirby Yes. Our contributor Aaron Lelevier have fixed that.

Answer (score 111):

You can use the [`get_user`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.1.5/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py#L182) method of the `auth` module. It says it wants a request as parameter, but it only ever uses the `session` attribute of the request. And it just so happens that our `Client` has that attribute.

```
from django.contrib import auth
user = auth.get_user(self.client)
assert user.is_authenticated
```

Comment: +1 this is a great answer and would make a useful assertion: https://gist.github.com/bengolder/c9dc7006f9d6b4d17d5af5465115df73

Comment: This does not work as of Django 2.0.5. First `is_authenticated` is now a property and not a callable. It doesn't return true even for a successful login as well.

Comment: `self.client.session['_auth_user_id']` (as [discussed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184861/308204)) works with Django >=2.0.

Comment: And I can confirm Chronial's answer works in Django >=2.0 (with pytest even) too. Just don't ever forget that in your views you always need to login your user after you've authenticated her. (I always forget that and think that authenticate() is enough).

Comment: Works for Django 3.0.2

Comment: I initially didn't understand this answer because I didn't understand get_user() and .is_authenticated. The docs note that .is_authenticated *always* returns True for a User db object. It will only be False on an anonymous user. For example, if you wanted to test logout, you would need to do `user = auth.get_user(self.client)` again after logout for user.is_authenticated == False (because the client now has an AnonymousUser).

Answer (score 11):

Django's TestClient has a [login method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login) which returns True if the user was successfully logged in.

Comment: Except it's not the test that does the login() call.

Comment: @Manur what do you mean? Does this change the usefulness of `self.assertTrue(self.client.login(credentials))`?

Answer (score 9):

The method `is_authenticated()` on the `User` model [always returns `True`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L89). `False` is returned for `request.user.is_authenticated()` in the case that `request.user` is an instance of `AnonymousUser`, which `is_authenticated()` method always returns `False`.
While testing you can have a look at `response.context['request'].user.is_authenticated()`.

You can also try to access another page in test which requires to be logged in, and see if `response.status` returns `200` or `302` (redirect from `login_required`).

Comment: What could be the reason that I don't have a response.request.user object? This is what the request dict looks like {'CONTENT_LENGTH': 244, 'wsgi.input': <django.test.client.FakePayload object at 0x31e9950>, 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST', 'PATH_INFO': '/register/', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=BoUnDaRyStRiNg', 'QUERY_STRING': ''}

Comment: Are you using `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`?

Comment: yep, using the default middleware.

Comment: The context is None also. I could add follow=True and then check response.context['user'].is_authenticated I guess.

Comment: the response.request object within tests from the test client is usually a dict, not the same as you would have in a normal http request.

Answer (score 2):

Where are you initialising your `self.client`?  What else is in your `setUp` method?  I have a similar test and your code should work fine.  Here's how I do it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client


class UserTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()

    def testLogin(self):
        print User.objects.all() # returns []
        response = self.client.post(reverse('auth-registration'), 
                            { 'username':'foo', 
                              'password1':'bar', 
                              'password2':'bar' } )
        print User.objects.all() # returns one user
        print User.objects.all()[0].is_authenticated() # returns True
```

**EDIT**

If I comment out my login logic, I don't get any User after `self.client.post(`.  If you really want to check if the user has been authenticated, use the `self.client` to access another url which requires user authentication.  Continuing from the above, access another page:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('another-page-which-requires-authentication'))
print response.status_code
```

The above should return 200 to confirm that the user has authenticated.  Anything else, it will redirect to the login page with a 302 code.

Comment: print User.objects.all()[0].is_authenticated() did you try testing that before you implemented your login logic? Cause what I understand from what the others said is that that will always return true. You need the request.user.is_authenticated. Also the django TestCase comes with a Client object already initialized so no need to do that twice.

Answer (score 2):

There is another succinct way, using `wsgi_request` in `response`:

```
response = self.client.post('/signup', data)
assert response.wsgi_request.user.is_authenticated()
```

and @Chronial 's manner is also available with `wsgi_request`:

```
from django.contrib import auth
user = auth.get_user(response.wsgi_request)
assert user.is_authenticated()
```

Because `response.wsgi_request` object has a `session` attribute.

However, I think using `response.wsgi_request.user` is more simple.