# django - get user logged into test client

Tags: django, testing

In a written django test, how can I get the current logged in user?

For example this is the test I want to write:

```
def test_author_set_once(self):
    self.client.login(username='Adam', password='password')
    #create an object and test the author is adam
    self.client.login(username='Barry', password='password')
    #modify the first object and test that the author has not changed
```

So I want to be able to say something like...

```
self.assertEqual(object.author, self.client.user)
```

(but I can't)

The way I've coded it at the moment is like this:

```
self.client.login(username='Adam', password='password')
self.user = User.objects.get(username='Adam')
#create an object 
self.assertEqual(object.author, self.user)
```

This relies on the assumption that the request.user is the same as a particular user object. I guess it's OK but it seems a bit clunky.

Is there anyway to avoid the assumption?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The test client is request-agnostic. It doesn't inherently hold information about what users are logged in. (Neither does your actual webserver or the Django dev server, either, for obvious reasons, and those same reasons apply here).

`login` is simply a convenience method on the test client to essentially mimic a POST to `/login/` with the defined user credentials. Nothing more.

The actual user is available on the `request` just like in a view. However, since you don't have direct access to the view, Django makes `request` available on the view's response. After  you actually use the test client to load a view, you can store the result and then get the user via:

```
response.request.user
```

More recent versions of Django will use:

```
response.wsgi_request.user
```

Comment: My response doesn't have user in the request dictionary.

Comment: Same here. Does not exist.

Comment: Okay folks. I added this answer **2 YEARS** ago. Unsurprisingly, Django apparently has changed *just a little* since then (like 3, count 'em, 3 major revisions). That's *not* a reason to start downvoting my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I think it is, you should edit it as developers may use it wrongly

Comment: @FábioDiniz: read the link. There's good reasons to downvote. This isn't one of them. Answers are a moment in time thing. If everyone was responsible for going back and editing every single answer they've ever given to make sure it's always up-to-date, it would be a full time job. I'm not even using Django anymore and haven't for the last two releases, so I have no clue what Django changed and what they didn't. Let's not be silly.

Comment: And, let's not forget that this is precisely why editing is available to *everyone*, even if you just have to wait for your edit to be approved. Those who are actively using a technology and know that something has changed can edit the answer without having to involve the original poster.

Comment: The problem isn't that you didn't update it, it's that your response *never stated* which version of Django you were using.  How any ol' editor is supposed to fix that without your help, I'm not sure ;)  I often forget version info as well; good reminder for all of us :)

Answer (score 42):

Actually you can't access the current user via a test client response.

However, you can check if some user is logged in. Inspecting `self.client.session` will do:

```
self.client.session['_auth_user_id']
>>> 1
```

There is a [more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013115) for this.

Comment: thank you - the above posters had gleefully chorused the "after you call the view and get a response in your test case" answer.

Comment: A [response to that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35871564/307511) proves that one can actually get the current user.

Comment: @hso Sorry, I don't feel much comfortable to edit your own answer to replace its main information. I learned about `get_user` from a response to my own answer then I updated it based on that better approach. As such, feel free to update yours. :)

Answer (score 13):

I don't know which version you are using. Since 1.10.2, there is a `wsgi_request` attribute in `response`, it serves as `request` object in your view.

So It's very simple to get logged in user:

```
response.wsgi_request.user
```

Answer (score 10):

You can [log in with a test user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13035268/4928578) like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
user = User.objects.create_user('foo', 'myemail@test.com', 'bar')
self.client.login(username='foo', password='bar')
```

Now, you can just use `user` in your tests:

`self.assertEqual(created_model_object.user, user)`