# Django testing: mock user login

Tags: django, testing

I would like to test a Django project:

template `news.html`:

```
{% if user.is_authentication %}
  <a href=#>Logout ({{user.username}})</a>
{% else %}
  <a href=#>Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

How do I create the situation that the user is already logged in (the `accounts` app, responsible for user login, has not implemented yet) such that the template will display the `Logout` link?

(a) Functional test:

```
def test_logged_in_user_can_see_logout_link(self):
    # A logged-in user arrives at the main page
    ## How to mock a logged-in user here? 
    self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
    self.assertTrue(self.browser.find_element_by_link_text('Logout'))
```

(b) Unit test:

```
def test_logged_in_user_can_see_logout_link**(self):
    # How to login the user here?
    request = self.factory.get('/news/')
    response = news(request)
    self.assertContains(response, 'Logout')
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660952/test-that-user-was-logged-in-successfully

Comment: But that discussed about "how to test if a user is logged in", not "login the user without actually calling the `accounts` app".

Answer (score 3):

In Django's base user, the property `is_authenticated` simply returns `True` in any case. On the AnonymousUser though it returns always `False`. The `login_required` decorator also checks for `user.is_authenticated`, by the way.

**(b)** Therefore, in the unit test scenario, you can easily pass a mocked object that also returns true for `mocked_object.is_authenticated`.

```
def test_logged_in_user_can_see_logout_link(self):

    class MockUser:
        is_authenticated = True

    request = self.factory.get('/news/')
    request.user = MockUser()
    response = news(request)
    self.assertContains(response, 'Logout')
```

**(a)** In the functional testing scenario however mocking is not so easy. I don't even think that it's recommended because these tests should actually test if all the parts that have already passed the unit tests work together flawlessly.

In the book ["Obey The Testing Goat"](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/) by Harry J.W. Percival [a session object is created before the first interaction between Selenium browser and site](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_fixtures_and_wait_decorator.html). The browser then uses that session cookie and is authenticated. It's a really nice trick.