# testing django user login by username?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-forms, django-testing

I am trying to run a test case on whether the register user is logged in or not

tests.py

```
class RegistrationFormTestCase(TestCase):


   def test_valid_form(self):
      response = self.client.post(reverse('user-registration'),

                                {
                                    'username':'admin99',
                                    'password1':'qwertyui',
                                    'password2':'qwertyui',
                                    'email':'admin@example.com',

                                })

     user = User.objects.get(username='admin99')
     self.assertEqual(response.status_code,302)
```

The following test case is getting passed and I want to check whether the user exists or not,
**response** is HttpResponse object. I have retrive the obtained username from response and compare it to the **user**

> eg:   self.assertEqual(response(username),user)

Any help would be apprectiated.Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: Django will throw `User.DoesNotExist` exception if user does not exist. You can use `assertRaises` to assert that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5661191/3951511
This will resolve your problem

Comment: I used response.status_code and i am getting 302..It worked ...here I am trying to assertEqual with username in the response with already registered user.