# How to make a POST request inside Django's Test.py with an authenticated user? (Token auth needed?)

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to find a way to test a POST-request which need an authenticated user in Django.

I'm using the login-option as described in the docs here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login

And I'm using the client.post method as described here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post

However, my response prints as "None" and I'm getting a 403, rather than a 200 as my view should return. It works fine when I'm trying it out with postman, so that's not where the problem lay.

**My test**

```
class TodoTests(TestCase):
    @classmethod

    # Set up test DB
    def setUpTestData(cls):

        # Create a user "alexanderlindgren"
        cls.user1 = User.objects.create(
            username="xxxxx",
            email="xxxxx@gmail.com",
            password="password123",
        )

    # Try creating a task a AUTHENTICATED user
    def test_post_new_task_authorized_user(self):
        self.client.login(username="xxxxx", password="password123")
        data = {
            "title": "A new post",
            "description": "Description of post",
            "responsible_username": "xxxxx",
        }
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("CUDtasks"), data, content_type="application/json"
        )
        print("REPONSE IS: %s" % response.context)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

**Test error code**

```
FAIL: test_post_new_task_authorized_user (todo.tests.TodoTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxx/Documents/Programmering/xxxx/myproject/todo/tests.py", line 140, in test_post_new_task_authorized_user
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 403 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.084s
```

I've also tried with "force_login", but still getting a 403:

```
  # Try creating a task a AUTHENTICATED user
    def test_post_new_task_authorized_user(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user1)
        data = {
            "title": "A new post",
            "description": "Description of post",
            "responsible_username": "alexanderlindgren",
        }
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("CUDtasks"), data, content_type="application/json"
        )
        print("REPONSE IS: %s" % response.context)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

**This is what I'm returning in my view:**

```
serialized_task = TaskSerializer(task_to_edit)

return Response(data={"Updated task": serialized_task.data}, status=200)
```

**EDIT:**
I've also checked that the user is logged in by doing the following, which don't trow any errors

```
self.assertEqual(int(self.client.session["_auth_user_id"]), self.user1.pk)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013115/16333505

**EDIT 2:**
I'm using a token based auth for DRF, and think it could be something to do with this, so I tried retrieving the token with a post request, but that fails as well with the POST request I'm doing. It's the right URL as I'm getting a 403 if I try to do a GET-request. This is weird.

```
response = self.client.post(
    "/api-token-auth",
    {"username": self.user1.username, "password": self.user1.password},
    content_type="application/json",
)
print(f"Response token: {response.context}")
self.assertEqual(
    response.status_code, 200, "The token should be successfully returned."
)
```

Comment: Hi! Have you created a user with those credentials?

Comment: You can also just create a user, and use [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) instead

Comment: @bdbd I've attached the creation of the user as well as tried with force_login, still same result.

Comment: Can you share the view? Does it also reach the view at all?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think so but I have problems with running my debugger in vscode, but from running PDB it don't seem to reach the view.